# How to hide scrollbar on React Apps for iOS

Tags: ios, css, reactjs

for React Apps, when i want to hide the scrollbar using WEKBIT apparently i doesn't work on iOS web-view.
i'm using this code :

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover,
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active,
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```

and it always shown up everytime, how do i fix that?

Comment: How is this related to React? Does it work for you in a regular document, but it doesn't work with React?

Comment: yeah i'm using react for apps on iOS, worked on Android but not iOS, i'm still using CSS for designing all pages.